# JavaScript formula to create grid

Tags: javascript, three.js

Im wanting to tile a grid of objects using JavaScript.I  have forgotten the formula, cant seem to find it online anywhere:

```
            var width = 113;
            var height = 113;
            var col = 10;
            var row = 10;

            for ( j = 0; j < col; j ++ ) {
                 var object = new object();
                 object.position.x = 0 + width * j
                 // do i nee another loop here?
                 //add object to....
             }
```

This will return a row of 10 objects spaced by their width but i also want columns like a 10x10 grid, just after the formula really in JavaScript..

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could nest two `for` loops, like this:

```
var width = 113;
var height = 113;
var col = 10;
var row = 10;

var space = ...;

// Rows loop
for ( j = 0; j < row; j ++ ) {
     // For each column in the row
     for ( i = 0; i < col; i ++ ) {
         // j is the row index and i is the column index..
         var object = new object();
         object.position.x = (width + space) * i;
         object.position.y = (height + space) * j;
         // Add object to...
     }
 }
```

Comment: I have updated my answer to include the formula for the placing of each object. I also added a `space` variable for the space in between each one.

Comment: i just added for reference as my memory is useless...thanks again